# Unable to find hadoop-env.sh in hadoop folder

Tags: hadoop

I am trying to install hadoop on Ubuntu 12.04. I followed the following article.

http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/

I have installed hadoop as per the instruction given in this tutorial. I have installed hadoop-0.23.9.tar.gz, though the site mentions an older version. It also mentions about updating hadoop-env.sh file. I could not find this file under /usr/local/hadoop/conf. There is no directory 'conf' under hadoop directory. It could be that this file is located somewhere else due to version change, but I am unable to find it. I want to know where this configuration file is located under the main hadoop directory.

Comment: Please check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15752423/how-to-install-hadoop-on-ubuntu) on [so].

Comment: It is probably in the `etc/hadoop` folder. Check that out.

Answer (score 5):

Run following command on terminal to find it :

```
find hadoop/ -name hadoop-env.sh
```

Replace hadoop/ with your hadoop folder name

Answer (score 3):

The usual location for the configuration and environment is in `/etc/hadoop`. Example: `hadoop-2.5.1//etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh`

Answer (score 0):

For the most recent hadoop release, the file `hadoop-env.sh` can be found in:

`/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/main/conf`

Answer (score 0):

You may search in this folder for hadoop_env.sh `/usr/local/hadoop{your_hadoop_folder_name}/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/main/conf/`